# Powershell - convert text fields into objects

Tags: object, powershell, text

I am trying to find an elegant way of transforming data below into collection of Powershell objects but unfortunately I am unable to find a simple way of doing it. Would someone be able to help me here?

> Name: ENC1
>   IPv4 Address: 172.16.2.101
>   Link Settings: Forced, 100 Mbit, Full Duplex
>   Name: ENC2
>   IPv4 Address: 172.16.2.103
>   Link Settings: Forced, 100 Mbit, Full Duplex
>   Name: ENC3
>   IPv4 Address: 172.16.2.103
>   Link Settings: Forced, 100 Mbps, Full Duplex
>   Name: ENC4
>   IPv4 Address: 172.16.2.104
>   Link Settings: Forced, 100 Mbps, Full Duplex

This is what I came up with.

> $out = @()
>   $text =  Get-Content input.txt
>   $count = 0
>   do {
>       $line = ($text | select -Skip $count -first 3)
>       $obj = "" | Select Name,IP,Settings
>       $obj.Name = $line[0].split(":")[1]
>       $obj.IP = $line[1].split(":")[1]
>        $obj.Settings = $line[2].split(":")[1]
>       $out += $obj
>       $count = $count+3
>   }
>    until ($count -eq $text.count)
>   $out

Is there simplier way of doing it?

Comment: That data has probably been transformed from something else - is there any way you can get access to that and possibly skip the parsing altogether?

Comment: the data is generated as a part of the script output. I would have to parse it one way or another.However it this case this is not relevant - the question was for any data that was presented this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a Switch:

```
$data = (@'
Name: ENC1
 IPv4 Address: 172.16.2.101
 Link Settings: Forced, 100 Mbit, Full Duplex
 Name: ENC2
 IPv4 Address: 172.16.2.103
 Link Settings: Forced, 100 Mbit, Full Duplex
 Name: ENC3
 IPv4 Address: 172.16.2.103
 Link Settings: Forced, 100 Mbps, Full Duplex
 Name: ENC4
 IPv4 Address: 172.16.2.104
 Link Settings: Forced, 100 Mbps, Full Duplex
'@).split("`n") |
foreach {$_.trim()}

Switch -Regex ($data) 
{
 '^Name: (.+)' {$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{Name=$Matches[1];IP=$null;Settings=$null}}
 '^IPv4 Address: (.+)' {$obj.IP = $matches[1]}
 '^Link Settings: (.+)' {$obj.Settings = $Matches[1];$obj}
}



Name                                 IP                                   Settings                            
----                                 --                                   --------                            
ENC1                                 172.16.2.101                         Forced, 100 Mbit, Full Duplex       
ENC2                                 172.16.2.103                         Forced, 100 Mbit, Full Duplex       
ENC3                                 172.16.2.103                         Forced, 100 Mbps, Full Duplex       
ENC4                                 172.16.2.104                         Forced, 100 Mbps, Full Duplex
```

Edit: after some consideration, I think I like this pattern better:

```
$DefValue = 'Parse error. Check input.'
Switch -Regex ($data) 
{
 '^Name: (.+)' {$obj;$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{Name=$Matches[1];IP=$DefValue;Settings=$DefValue}}
 '^IPv4 Address: (.+)' {$obj.IP = $matches[1]}
 '^Link Settings: (.+)' {$obj.Settings = $Matches[1]}
}
```

Comment: i dont undertand the last line. Why do we have to append ";$obj" to make it works ?

Comment: @Kayasax - That puts the finished object onto the pipeline.  Without that, it just gets destroyed when $obj gets created as a new object when it hits then next Name line.

Comment: +1 Cool solution. Learned something new today. I would have tried to split at `Name:` and done it the hard way :)

Comment: I was previously impressed by your [Powershell multiline regex matching](http://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/powershell-multiline-regex-matching/) post that demonstrated a solution with, in a sense, only two lines of code (not counting the code to prepare the data). But this is yet another elegant solution!

Comment: Thanks!  I added an alternate solution that does a better job (IMHO) of detecting possible missing entries in the input data.

Comment: Thank you x1,000,000. I was messing with ConvertFrom-StringData for *hours* before finding this.